# How to programmatically get webform drafts for a specific user?

Tags: 8, webforms

How to fetch all the webform drafts saved based on user id?

I tried the below query and it gives me all submission id's but how do I get just the drafts

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
      ->condition('uid', 123)
      ->condition('webform_id','test_1');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
  ->condition('uid', 123)
  ->condition('webform_id, 'test_1')
  ->condition('in_draft', TRUE);

$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

Or via the `EntityTypeManager`:

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface[] $submissions */
$submissions = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('webform_submission')
  ->loadByProperties([
    'uuid' => 123,
    'webform_id' => 'test_1',
    'in_draft' => TRUE,
  ]);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use entityQuery, it's more readable and loadByProperties by property may be deprecated in the future.